# Private pages for users

Tags: ee5, users

is it possible in expressionengine 5 to have private pages?

I know it's possible to create a forum but what about pages with content just for registered users?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes private pages are easily do-able. There are numerous approaches, here's one using a template to control who can view content.

Create a template and add some conditional tags to determine if the person is logged out (show login form), or logged in (show the content)

**Assuming that anyone that is logged in can see content**

```
{if logged_out}
  YOUR LOGIN FORM
{/if}

{if logged_in}
  YOUR PRIVATE CONTENT
{/if}
```

**Only allow access to a specific member group**

```
{if logged_out}
  YOUR LOGIN FORM
{/if}

<!-- only allow member group 5 to access content -->        
{if logged_in_group_id == "5"}
  YOUR PRIVATE CONTENT
{/if}

<!-- if logged in member group is not 5 -->
{if logged_in_group_id != "5"}
 You're logged in but not allowed to see content
{/if}
```

Comment: Cool! This is great thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

EE doc search works pretty well these days, and the info is all there.

Login and registration: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/member/index.html

Member groups: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/member-manager.html#member-groups

Controlling access to templates: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/control-panel/template-manager.html#access

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes It's true EE doc search works pretty well if you know the specific topic you looking for :-) My question was more where to start ... This is a great start thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the method of going into a template's settings, Access tab, and checking "Enable HTTP Authentication". That checkbox, combined with the member groups you check to have access right above it can also password-protect certain templates.